# How to solve bower install error?

Tags: polymer, bower, bower-install, polymer-2.x

I am currently working on Polymer 2.0.
I am trying install new custom element like iron-form and paper-material.
But bower install command gives error like below ,
[image]

How to solve this error.

Comment: Probably not related but Bower states the following:
⚠️ As of the 2.0 release, this element is deprecated in favour of the shared styles in PolymerElements/paper-styles. Please see the implementation of PolymerElements/paper-button for an example.

Comment: It also showing errors for all other elements and also while creating new element.4

Answer (score 0):

Please share your bower.json file here.  But incase if you feel your bower.json file is clear. then delete bower_compenents directory and then at CLI > bower update.  This will update/reinstall your dependencies clearly. If you use polymer #^2.0  (over 2.0 ver) then consider dependencies over ^2.0 is also comptable with polymer  below versions of 2.0.

iron-form element comptable with polymer 1.1.0, This mean: when you try to install with :

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-form
```

You will be faced with :

```
Unable to find a suitable version for polymer, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
   1) polymer#^1.1.0 which resolved to 1.9.2 and is required by iron-form#1.1.5
    2) polymer#^1.5.0 which resolved to 1.9.2 and is required by iron-ajax#1.4.4
    3) polymer#^1.0.0 which resolved to 1.9.2 and is required by promise-polyfill#1.0.1
    4) polymer#^2.0.0-rc.3 which resolved to 2.0.1 and is required by app-layout#1233b73c35, polymer-starter-kit
```

(this is just example.) You should choice your current polymer versions as it is 4 and compatible with previous verisons.

In case of your shared more information, I will try to add more information if needed.